# How to analyze social media data to see its impact on a game's sales

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, feature-extraction, bert, transfer-learning

I work for a console gaming giant. We forecasted the sales for a RPG game that was to be released few months back. But the actual sales was twice the forecast. This compelled the developers to investigate what role did social media has to play on this games' sales using state-of-the-art transfer learning and deep learning models. I'm supposed to send them a proposal with the findings. For my analysis I'm planning to use few other comparable games but with poor actual sales. I'll engineer features from Social media data and compare them as the key KPIs. I want to understand the following

1. Which social media platforms would be best to extract data from?
2. What features should I extract from these platform and how?
3. How can I use deep learning and transfer learning models in the best
   possible way?

Thank you